# Why can't this as a return type in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In the following code, I add a fun myGet to data class  WiFiDef, I hope the fun myGet can return a object of  WiFiDef.

but these code can't be compiled, the error hint is Type expected, why? How can I fix it? Thanks!

```
data class WiFiDef(
        val isChecked: Boolean = true,
        val name: String,
        val status: Boolean = false
) : DeviceDef {
    fun myGet(mContext: Context) : this {     //Error hint: Type expected
        return WiFiHelper(mContext).getWiFi()
    }
}   


class WiFiHelper(val mContext: Context) {

    fun getWiFi(): WiFiDef {      
        ..
        return WiFiDef(isChecked =aIsChecked, name= name, status = isEnabled)
    }

}
```

Comment: change : this to : WifiDef

Comment: The function signature needs to be: `fun my get(mContext: Context): WiFiDef`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not a type, it refers to the current instance of the class that you're in. A method can't return with a type of `this` just like it can't with an `x` where `x` is a variable.

Instead, as @Angel Koh has already pointed out in the comment, you should make your method have the return type that matches the type of expression you're returning in it, which in this case is a `WiFiDef`, since that's what your `getWiFi` method returns:

```
fun myGet(mContext: Context): WiFiDef {
    return WiFiHelper(mContext).getWiFi()
}
```